# Alignment of labels in enumitem

Tags: enumitem

[image]

I'm trying to simulate a bibliography environmnet trough `enumitem`. I've already used `bibliography` for book references and I want to add the sites in the image separately. Both the bibliography and the sitography are done manually.

I'm wondering if I can align the labels centering the letters. The standard alignment is with respect to "]". I tried to use the commands "align=left" and "align=parleft", but without any satisfying result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt plus 2pt, labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt plus 2pt, labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Sitografia}
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\Alph*]}]
\item \label{iucn} \url{www.iucnredlist.org}
\item \label{berna}\url{www.minambiente.it/pagina/convenzione-di-berna}
\item \label{bonn}\href{www.minambiente.it/pagina/cms-convenzione-di-bonn\#sthash.CdKnexMn.dpuf}
      {\nolinkurl{www.minambiente.it/pagina/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{cms-convenzione-di-bonn\#sthash.CdKnexMn.dpuf}
              }
\item \label{cites}\url{www.cites.org/eng/disc/text.php#III}
\item \label{asp}\href{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/archivio/allegati/biodiversita/protocollo_ASP.pdf}
      {\nolinkurl{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{archivio/allegati/biodiversita/protocollo_ASP.pdf}
              }


\item \label{direttiva}\href{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/archivio/allegati/rete_natura_2000/Regolamento_D.P.R._8_settembre_1997_n._357.PDF}
       {\nolinkurl{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{archivio/allegati/rete_natura_2000/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{Regolamento_D.P.R._8_settembre_1997_n._357.PDF}
             }



\item \label{ce}\href{www.ambientediritto.it/Legislazione/Caccia/2006/reg_2006_1967_ce.pdf}
       {\nolinkurl{wwww.ambientediritto.it/Legislazione/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{Caccia/2006/reg_2006_1967_ce.pdf}
             }

\item \label{lino}\href{www.tanogabo.com/alcuni-nidi-di-tartarughe-di-mare-in-sicilia/}
      {\nolinkurl{www.tanogabo.com/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{alcuni-nidi-di-tartarughe-di-mare-in-sicilia/}
         }

\item \label{ted}\href{www.web.archive.org/web/20070930201026/http://www.hsus.org/wildlife/issues_facing_wildlife/turtle_excluder_device_ted.html}
       {\nolinkurl{www.web.archive.org/web/20070930201026/http://}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{www.hsus.org/wildlife/issues_facing_wildlife/}
              \\
              \nolinkurl{turtle_excluder_device_ted.html}
             }

\item \label{amo}\href{www.libreriainternazionaleilmare.blogspot.com/2011/10/ami-circolari-per-salvare-la-caretta.html}
      {\nolinkurl{www.libreriainternazionaleilmare.blogspot.com/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{2011/10/ami-circolari-per-salvare-la-caretta.html}
             }
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

PS: Also, do you have any idea why some urls work and other don't? I used the same syntax to write them.

Comment: Could you please add the code with which you are trying to achieve this in the form of an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I just put the label in a centered `\makebox`, as in `\begin{enumerate}[label={\makebox[2.5ex]{[\Alph*]}}]`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt plus 2pt, labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt plus 2pt, labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Sitografia}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\makebox[2.5ex]{[\Alph*]}}]
\item \label{iucn} \url{www.iucnredlist.org}
\item \label{berna}\url{www.minambiente.it/pagina/convenzione-di-berna}
\item \label{bonn}\href{www.minambiente.it/pagina/cms-convenzione-di-bonn\#sthash.CdKnexMn.dpuf}
      {\nolinkurl{www.minambiente.it/pagina/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{cms-convenzione-di-bonn\#sthash.CdKnexMn.dpuf}
              }
\item \label{cites}\url{www.cites.org/eng/disc/text.php#III}
\item \label{asp}\href{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/archivio/allegati/biodiversita/protocollo_ASP.pdf}
      {\nolinkurl{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{archivio/allegati/biodiversita/protocollo_ASP.pdf}
              }


\item \label{direttiva}\href{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/archivio/allegati/rete_natura_2000/Regolamento_D.P.R._8_settembre_1997_n._357.PDF}
       {\nolinkurl{www.minambiente.it/sites/default/files/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{archivio/allegati/rete_natura_2000/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{Regolamento_D.P.R._8_settembre_1997_n._357.PDF}
             }



\item \label{ce}\href{www.ambientediritto.it/Legislazione/Caccia/2006/reg_2006_1967_ce.pdf}
       {\nolinkurl{wwww.ambientediritto.it/Legislazione/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{Caccia/2006/reg_2006_1967_ce.pdf}
             }

\item \label{lino}\href{www.tanogabo.com/alcuni-nidi-di-tartarughe-di-mare-in-sicilia/}
      {\nolinkurl{www.tanogabo.com/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{alcuni-nidi-di-tartarughe-di-mare-in-sicilia/}
         }

\item \label{ted}\href{www.web.archive.org/web/20070930201026/http://www.hsus.org/wildlife/issues_facing_wildlife/turtle_excluder_device_ted.html}
       {\nolinkurl{www.web.archive.org/web/20070930201026/http://}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{www.hsus.org/wildlife/issues_facing_wildlife/}
              \\
              \nolinkurl{turtle_excluder_device_ted.html}
             }

\item \label{amo}\href{www.libreriainternazionaleilmare.blogspot.com/2011/10/ami-circolari-per-salvare-la-caretta.html}
      {\nolinkurl{www.libreriainternazionaleilmare.blogspot.com/}
             \\
              \nolinkurl{2011/10/ami-circolari-per-salvare-la-caretta.html}
             }
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can make the brackets be equally spaced, with `\begin{enumerate}[label={[\makebox[1.5ex]{\Alph*}]}]`

[image]